# Copy text file to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, text, copy, row

I'm using this code, and its working.
But my text file is to long, so I can't see all the text.
Its like the height of the row reached the limit.

What can I do?

Maybe copy one row from the text file to one row in the Excel worksheet.

```
Sub CopyTextFile()

Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile : Set oFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(""L:\00010\COMPANY.bat"", 1)
Dim sText

sText = oFile.ReadAll

oFile.Close

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Text file").Range("A1").Value = sText

End Sub
```

Comment: import a csv file without vba, using [get & transform](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/getting-started-with-power-query-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a) buid-in function of Excel (2010+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim comp, path1 As String

    comp = "COMPANY"
    path1 = "TEXT;L:\00010\COMPANY.bat"

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=path1, _
        Destination:=Range("C1"))

        .Name = comp
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With

End Sub
```